# Filesystem issues every other day

Tags: 20.04, filesystem

I have a filesystem issue that shows itself by making everything read-only then I have to reboot the system and run fsck -y to correct the errors and then it'll run again for a day.

Is there a fix? If I haven't given enough information ask and I'll provide it.

Dan.

Comment: Did you check your HD for errors?

Comment: Sounds like a failing hard drive. As a failsafe, the root file system will turn read-only when a fault is detected. If this keeps happening then the hard drive is probably on its way out

Comment: Are you using a supported Ubuntu release? Which? Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Edit your question and show me a screenshot of the `Disks` app **SMART Data & Tests** window data. Enlarge the window so the screenshot captures all of the data for me to see. Also show me `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.